# Can I select in JQuery id & class own by the same element?

Tags: jquery

I create a system who add & remove class, the goal is to change the css with in Jquery but only if the button had an "X" class AND "Y" id.
Is it possible ?

```
            if ($(".NotSelect, #reponse1")) {
                $(this).css("background-color","green")
                $(this).prop('disabled', false);       
            } else if($(".Select, #reponse1")){
                $(this).css("background-color","red")
                $(this).prop('disabled', true);            }
```

Comment: Like this: `if($(element).hasClass('X') && $(element).id() == 'Y') { true }` ? Or, you can select the element by its ID, and check if it has the class `if($('#Y').hasClass('X')) { true }`. But I got the feeling that we are not seeing your full code here....

Comment: You can simply use `$('.NotSelect#reponse1')` & `$('.Select#reponse1')`. **Do not use space or comma** between `selectors` so it will select element which has `.NotSelect` `class` and `response1` `id` for `$('.NotSelect#reponse1')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use .hasClass("YourClass") method of jquery

```
if($('#response1').hasClass('NotSelected')){
    $(this).css("background-color","green")
    $(this).prop('disabled', false);
}else{
    $(this).css("background-color","red")
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
}
```

Comment: You dont need the dot `.` in `hasClass('.NotSelected')`

Answer (score 0):

What I can understand is that, how to make changes on an element only if it has an id, say "X", and a class, say "Y".

Do do that, you gotta do something like this :

```js
if($(this).is('#X.Y')){
    $(this).css("background-color","green");
    $(this).prop('disabled', false);
}
else{
    $(this).css("background-color","red");
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
}
```

**NOTE :** I am assuming here that `this` is referring to the button element you want to make check on. And don't forget to replace "X" and "Y" with the desired id and class.